# Cordova prevent webview drag on field focus?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have these preferences in my config.xml

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

I also use this CSS on the container holding a field

```
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
```

This disables the scroll BUT if I click/focus a field and drag, my container still drags. How do I disable that? This only happens when I touchdown a field and drag it..

**Edit:** I removed the UIWebViewBounce preference as it's not supported by Cordova but still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only answering to close. The issue wasn't related, there was a mistake in my code at another level.

Answer (score 1):

try using these styles on your container

```
user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
```

also try setting the `draggable` attribute to `false` on your HTML element

see docs :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable